# Forgotten backup PIN

Tags: password

I accidentally entered the pattern on my android phone wrong too many times. It now wants a backup pin to unlock. I remember the pattern and can get into my google account, but have forgotten my backup pin. I then locked it with Android Device Manager, and can see that lock screen, but it doesn't seem to give me a password entry field. If I click the back button it takes me to the backup pin entry field. I would really like to avoid resetting my phone. How can I reset my phone?

Comment: Still need an answer?

Comment: If you have access to your notification drawer, [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.gillion.lockedphonebackup) will recover all your internal storage when installed through desktop site. Make sure to follow instructions before installing.